# how to set off an alarm or alert with alert sound lasting until user presses a button in native script

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I've just started learning Native script and I'm working on a project that checks a price for a certain item and alerts the user if the price has reached the set amount. I want the alert to last until the user takes an action to turn it off similar to when you set an alarm and have to press "stop" for it to end. Is there a thing I can call to make that happen, also I need the alert to bypass silence mode and basically function just like the alarm clock but able to be triggered at any time. any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you planning to check for price updates in background or it's going to be a push notification from server side?

Comment: @manoj yes, there will be a process running in the background checking the price

Comment: iOS doesn't allow notification sound beyond 30 secs, but you may play music in background until user clicks on the notification action.